# How to have R 4.1 on Debian 11? Debian 11 won't update

Tags: debian, apt, r

1. Debian 11 only updates to R 4.0.4.
2. I have packages that require at least R 4.1.0 to be installed.
3. I already tried adding the official R repository to the source list as [the official website tells to do](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/#debian-bullseye-stable), but I get the following limitation.

> sudo apt update
>
> 20 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
>
> apt list --upgradable
>
> r-base-core/bullseye-cran40 4.3.2-1~bullseyecran.0 amd64 [upgradable from: 4.0.4-1]
>
> r-base-dev/bullseye-cran40 4.3.2-1~bullseyecran.0 all [upgradable from: 4.0.4-1]
>
> r-base/bullseye-cran40 4.3.2-1~bullseyecran.0 all [upgradable from: 4.0.4-1]
>
> r-cran-boot/bullseye-cran40 1.3-28.1-1~bullseyecran.0 all [upgradable from: 1.3-27-1]
>
> r-cran-class/bullseye-cran40 7.3-22-2~bullseyecran.0 amd64 [upgradable from: 7.3-18-1]
>
> r-cran-cluster/bullseye-cran40 2.1.4-1~bullseyecran.0 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.1.1-1]
>
> r-cran-codetools/bullseye-cran40 0.2-19-1~bullseyecran.0 all [upgradable from: 0.2-18-1]
>
> r-cran-foreign/bullseye-cran40 0.8.85-1~bullseyecran.0 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.8.81-1]
>
> r-cran-kernsmooth/bullseye-cran40 2.23-22-1~bullseyecran.0 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.23-18-1]
>
> r-cran-lattice/bullseye-cran40 0.22-5-1~bullseyecran.0 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.20-41-1+b1]
>
> r-cran-littler/bullseye-cran40 0.3.18-2~bullseyecran.0 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.3.12-1]
>
> r-cran-mass/bullseye-cran40 7.3-60-2~bullseyecran.0 amd64 [upgradable from: 7.3-53.1-1]
>
> r-cran-matrix/bullseye-cran40 1.6-1.1-1~bullseyecran.0 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.3-2-1]
>
> r-cran-mgcv/bullseye-cran40 1.9-0-1~bullseyecran.0 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.8-34-1]
>
> r-cran-nlme/bullseye-cran40 3.1.163-1~bullseyecran.0 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.1.152-1]
>
> r-cran-nnet/bullseye-cran40 7.3-19-2~bullseyecran.0 amd64 [upgradable from: 7.3-15-1]
>
> r-cran-rpart/bullseye-cran40 4.1.21-1~bullseyecran.0 amd64 [upgradable from: 4.1-15-2+b1]
>
> r-cran-spatial/bullseye-cran40 7.3-17-1~bullseyecran.0 amd64 [upgradable from: 7.3-13-1]
>
> r-cran-survival/bullseye-cran40 3.5-7-1~bullseyecran.0 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.2-7-1]
>
> r-recommended/bullseye-cran40 4.3.2-1~bullseyecran.0 all [upgradable from: 4.0.4-1]
>
> sudo apt upgrade
>
> The following packages have been kept back:
>
> r-base r-base-core r-base-dev r-cran-boot r-cran-class r-cran-cluster r-cran-codetools r-cran-foreign r-cran-kernsmooth r-cran-lattice r-cran-littler
>
> r-cran-mass r-cran-matrix r-cran-mgcv r-cran-nlme r-cran-nnet r-cran-rpart r-cran-spatial r-cran-survival r-recommended

Comment: Did you try requesting an explicit installation of the newer version with`apt install r-base=4.3.2-1~bullseyecran.0`?

Comment: FYI: Debian 12 has version 4.2.2 in its repository.

Comment: @Hermann This worked, but why REMOVED "r-cran-callr r-cran-dbitest r-cran-dbplyr r-cran-decor r-cran-devtools r-cran-dplyr r-cran-ggplot2 r-cran-isoband r-cran-mockery r-cran-pkgbuild r-cran-pkgload r-cran-processx r-cran-ps r-cran-rcmdcheck r-cran-rematch2 r-cran-roxygen2 r-cran-testthat r-cran-tibble r-cran-tidyr r-cran-tikzdevice r-cran-vdiffr r-cran-waldo r-cran-xopen" ?

Comment: why not upgrade to 12? It is a fairly painless process.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I'm pursuing a master degree and need R for one of the disciplines. Upgrading the OS will be painful right now, as I don't have time to have more problems to solve.

Comment: @Hermann Your solution solved my problem, thank you. Would you like to formally provide an answer to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try requesting an explicit installation of the newer version with this command:

```
apt install r-base=4.3.2-1~bullseyecran.0
```

The part after the equals sign denotes the version string.